# Can't get multiple DS18B20 to work. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: ds18b20

I am really struggling with this one. I want to attach multiple (5 or so would be nice) DS18B20 sensors (3 meter cable), but I can't get more than two to function. Two will show up in the devices folder with their proper address, but once I attach more this is all I get:

[image: Terminal view of the problem]

- I have tried so many things, 3.3v, 5v, parasitic mode, all to no
  avail.
- I attached all sensors one at a time, and they all showed up.
- I got a new raspberry Pi, same thing.
- I have a 47k Ohm resistor from + to data.
- Tried a stronger power source for the raspberry (2.5A instead of 2A), no change.

Since the sensors worked when attached by one by one, I am assuming that the wiring is correct.

Here's a pic of the wiring nonetheless:

[image: Sensor wiring]

As you can see I am using Wago connectors instead of a breadboard. From left to right: ground (goes to the ground pin obviously), data (goes to gpio 4, pin 7), and 5v/3v. The 47k ohm resistor connects data and 5v/3v.

I'd be grateful for any help or pointers to finally get this to work.

Comment: 47k? Sounds way to high. Are you sure it's not 4k7?

Comment: ahhhh I am such an idiot, I bought 47k instead of 4k7!!!! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm closing this question the problem is based on a typo or other arbitrary error and is unlikely to be of use to posterity.

Answer (score 1):

Well it turns out I bought 47k ohm instead of 4.7k ohm resistors. Now everything makes sense again!